# not able to run kdb q.exe in windows 10

Tags: kdb

I have downloaded kdb from kx.xom, copied q to c:/ directory and added QHOME environment variable. When I double click or run from cmd prompt, it freezes forever. my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Check this discussion:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/personal-kdbplus/windows$2010/personal-kdbplus/3Z4St-b6rP8/FaCd0EdSFAAJ

Comment: don't double click on it. open up an dos prompt run it from command line manually.

Comment: Rahul, I'm not able to open link you provided.
I have tried with cmd prompt also, it freezes.

Comment: use this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/personal-kdbplus/3Z4St-b6rP8  . If that doesnt work then search for this text in google: "Has anyone tried kdb on win10?"

Comment: thanks Rahul..I'm able to setup by following the link you provided